# Test Class Help increasing %

Tags: unit-test

[image]         public class CancelOrder {

```
    public NovaPOS_Gateway_Order__c cancel{get; set;}
    public boolean isactive{get; set;}
    String Accountid = '';
    public list<NovaPOS_Gateway_Accounts__c> accs;

    public CancelOrder() {
        accs = new list<NovaPOS_Gateway_Accounts__c>(); 
        cancel = new NovaPOS_Gateway_Order__c();
        Accountid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accid');
        accs = [select id,Active__c,NovaPOS_Location__c,(select id from NovaPOS_Gateway_Order__r where EMV_Device_Sent_to_Shipping_Address__c = true) from 
                              NovaPOS_Gateway_Accounts__c where id =:Accountid];

        isactive = false;

        if(accs.size() > 0)
        {
            integer Counter = 0;

            for(NovaPOS_Gateway_Order__c Ord : accs[0].NovaPOS_Gateway_Order__r)
            {
                if(Counter == 0)
                    isactive = true;
                else
                    isactive = false;

                Counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    public pagereference Finish()
    {
        cancel.NovaPOS_Gateway_Accounts__c = Accountid;
        cancel.RecordTypeid = Schema.SObjectType.NovaPOS_Gateway_Order__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('NovaPOS Gateway Cancellation Order').getRecordTypeId();
        if(isactive == false)
        cancel.NGO_Cancellation_Reason__c = 'Sold Location';

        insert cancel;

        if(!accs.isEmpty() && isactive == true)
        {
           NovaPOS_Location__c oRecord = new NovaPOS_Location__c();
            oRecord.id = accs[0].NovaPOS_Location__c ; 
            oRecord.Free_Model_Verified_Locked__c = false; 
            oRecord.Is_Location_on_GSPayTech_Gateway__c= false; 
            oRecord.Is_Location_on_the_Flexible_Model__c = false;
            oRecord.Free_Model_Verified_Locked__c =  false;
            oRecord.Payment_Gateways__c = '';
            oRecord.NAB_Merchant_Number__c = ''; 
            oRecord.Auhorize_Net_Transaction_Key__c = '';
            oRecord.Authorize_Net_Login_ID__c = '';
            oRecord.Status__c = 'Inactive';
            Update oRecord;
            Update accs;
        }

        PageReference reference=new PageReference('/'+cancel.id);
        reference.setRedirect(true);
        return reference;
    }

}
```

**Test Class**

```
     @istestpublic class CancelOrder_Test {   
    @istest static void testAccountChangeToNonDemo()
    {
        list<NovaPOS_Gateway_Accounts__c> accs = new list<NovaPOS_Gateway_Accounts__c>(); 
        // create an account
        Account account = new Account (Name = 'test');
        insert account;

        // crate a location
        NovaPOS_Location__c location = new NovaPOS_Location__c (Account__C = account.id, name = 'Test');
        insert location;

        // create a Gateway Account
        NovaPOS_Gateway_Accounts__c gatewayAccount = new NovaPOS_Gateway_Accounts__c (Account_del__c = account.id, NovaPOS_Location__c =location.id);
        insert gatewayAccount;

        accs.add(gatewayAccount);

        // add another location
        location = new NovaPOS_Location__c (Account__C = account.id, name = 'Test 2', Location_ID__c=1);
        insert location;

        gatewayAccount.NovaPOS_Location__c = location.id;
        update gatewayAccount;

        Boolean isactive = true;
        NovaPOS_Gateway_Order__c gatewayorder = new NovaPOS_Gateway_Order__c(NovaPOS_Gateway_Accounts__c = gatewayAccount.id,Terminal_Model__c = 'External Device',EMV_Device_Sent_to_Shipping_Address__c = true);


        NovaPOS_Gateway_Order__c cancel = new NovaPOS_Gateway_Order__c();
        cancel.NovaPOS_Gateway_Accounts__c = Account.id;

        cancel.NGO_Cancellation_Reason__c = 'Sold Location';


        apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put('accid' , gatewayAccount.Id);
        CancelOrder oc = new CancelOrder();
        oc.Finish();

    }
 }
```

Test covergae is 56% but I am unable to acheive more can anyone help me out !Line 21 and 42 aren't getting covered in Developer Console

Answer (score 1):

you are not setting the value of the accid to set the AccountID in the class for the query to return results.

Replace

```
apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put('accid' , gatewayAccount.Id);
```

with

```
PageReference pr = Page.YOURPAGENAME; //you will need the name of your VF page here
pr.getParameters().put('accid',gatewayAccount.id);

test.setCurrentPage(pr);
```

This will set the context for the controller and you getParameters in your class will get the AccountId form the URL.

you should also read up on Testing best practices as you have no asserts and are not verifying that what you expect to happen actually does. Testing in more than just covering lines.

there is a lot more that needs addressed in your test though.

Comment: Coverage remains same ! :-(\

Comment: Ahh my bad, you naming convention threw me off. Check answer again in a minute

Comment: Eric , as i am using 
PageReference reference=new PageReference('/'+cancel.id);
        reference.setRedirect(true);
        return reference;
    }
In my class then what should I add in 
PageReference pr = New pageReference('YOURPAGENAME');

Comment: But you are not setting the current page in the test `test.setCurrentPage()`

Comment: Can you please edit the above code

Comment: With what? not sure what else you need. Made a small change so you understand where it goes

Comment: No effect by adding  that too ! coverage still same and even i have uploaded picture of not covering of lines

Comment: @AppProject - So you did not get any additional coverage at all? Seems to me that is not accurate as the lines you showed are not lines 21 and you should now be covering this inside of `if(accs.size() > 0)`. For what you show in the screen do you ever insert `gatewayorder`? If not then that would be why as the relationship returns 0 records. Basic troubleshooting stuff here

Comment: i didnt get any code coverage here , i too dont know why its not covering the code

Comment: So you got NO increase of coverage? Suggest you take a step back, read, digest, take one step at a time and try to troubleshoot. this is all basic stuff with ALOT of documentation about it out there. You need to understand these fundamentals before you can apply answer given here with someone writing the entire test for you

Comment: If i insert gatewayorder then error comes 
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID 301120000008qYT. Flow error messages: <b>An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow</b><br>An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow.  Please contact your system administrator for more information.  Contact your administrator for help.: []

Comment: Then you need to troubleshoot your flow or figure out the requirements of the record as it need to be present to cover those lines (still not actually testing anything). You have a lot of issues here and this site is not geared toward solving multiple issues across an org. Suggest you start your learning by going to trailhead.salesforce.com